# Is it possible to scan a bluetooth device to find it's capabilities

Tags: bluetooth

I am looking for a way to scan a device I own and discover "what it can do".

In other words, I'd like to know if a device is able to describe the way you have to communicate with it in order to build some application around it.

In my case it is a simple Christmas light that I'd like to play with but this could be used in different situations.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is called Services. Any Bluetooth enabled device (classic or LE) publish its capabilities as services list. You simple have to check which services your device supports.

Answer (score 0):

**For classic bluetooth (BR/EDR):**

When scanning for bluetooth devices (Inquiry), the bluetooth device will send an inquiry response (if it wants to be discovered) and maybe also an extended inquiry response (EIR). This EIR may already contain a list of services, the devices supports. This is a very fast way to get a picture of a remote device.

Moreover, the service discovery protocol (SDP) gives more information on a device. This takes some more steps. In SDP two devices can exchange their capabilites in kind of ping pong process.

**For BLE:**

After connecting a BLE device usually a service discovery takes place. The BLE peripheral (e.g. headset or a light) reports its capabilities to the central (e.g. smart phone). Some of these services have [predefines functionalities](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services). Additionally, it is free to the manufacturer to add custom services.